# add and implement a custom validator to JSF dynamic form

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am building my JSF form dynamically using the `javax.faces.component` like:

```
...
} else if ((formFields.get(i).getFieldType().equals("Numeric"))) {
    HtmlInputText input = (HtmlInputText)application.createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    input.setId("G000"+i);
    input.setValueExpression("value", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{reviewReportBean.cRReviewerFormDataList["+i+"].fieldData}" , String.class));
    input.setDisabled(checkTaskStatus(taskId));
    //input.addValidator(numericValidator);
    dynamicPanelGrid.getChildren().add(input);
...
```

I would like to add & implement a numeric validator to inputText field dynamically. i have no idea how to implement?

For example if i try to validate using a regular expression, how can i add the relevant component (e.g. In a static form represented with `f:validateRegex` pattern="") dynamically? Is there any relevant interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for best use and i have also implemented validation through `JAVA SCRIPT` in JSF,

**code(JAVASCRIPT validation):**

```
htmlInputTextObj.setMaxlength(8);
htmlInputTextObj.setOnkeypress("javascript:return limitinput(event, '0123456789', true);");
htmlInputTextObj.setOnfocus("javascript:return clearThisField(this);");
htmlInputTextObj.setOnblur("javascript:return loadDefaultValue(this);");
```

**Code(JAVA validation)**

```
final LengthValidator validator =

     (LengthValidator)getApplication().createValidator(LengthValidator.VALIDATOR_ID);

   if (question.getMinLength() > 0)

     validator.setMinimum(question.getMinLength());

   if (question.getMaxLength() > 0)

     validator.setMaximum(question.getMaxLength());

   htmlInputText.addValidator(validator);
```

JAVA validator more reference use [link](http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/thoughts/frameworks/JSF.Techniques-Adding.Components.Dynamically.htm)

Comment: but with javascript it will be more difficult to achieve more complex  validator logic

Comment: ya thats true, but its less complex to add validation into code.

Comment: jubin thanks for responding, i will check! Another option i think i could have is that i could add (if supported) a component of type 'f:validateRegex' after my inputText component. But i can not find if it is supported (javax.faces.*)

Comment: Is this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/validator/RegexValidator.html) its corresponding clasS? javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator

Comment: yes they give example for JSF dynamic component and validator use